# Short story: child made less intelligent and less attractive

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

What is the name of the early to mid-1950's sci-fi short story in which an asteroid miner and his wife decide to have their pretty, intelligent daughter dumbed down and made less attractive?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You might be able to improve this question by checking out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407).

Comment: I was thinking of Vonnegut's [Harrison Bergeron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrison_Bergeron), which has the dumbing down and making less attractive (and less physically fit) in common, but the main character is a boy (though there is a girl who is given the same treatment), and it takes place on Earth, so probably not it?

Answer (score 17):

It's not an exact match - the parents aren't miners, they're farmers, and the setting is a planet at Deneb, not an asteroid - but I'm still going to suggest this is [*No Charge for Alterations*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?73499) by H.L. Gold.

The time frame matches (first published in 1953, anthologized 1955), as does the plot.  (The daughter is not a good fit for a farming planet, so is "altered" to be happier and productive.)

You can read the entire story online at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/31986/31986-h/31986-h.htm).

Also the (unaccepted) answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/208278/dumbing-down-a-child-for-practical-reasons)

Comment: It's weird how in both questions, the OP thinks things happen with miners on an asteroid instead of farmers on a planet.

Comment: @Echox Yeah, I meant to come back and put a comment to that effect.  I'm still considering that there may be another story out there, but so far I can't find it.